# Is it possible to measure a thread's execution time without including blocking/preemption time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, execution-time

In C#.NET, is there a way to measure the actual CPU time of a thread/task. This time should NOT include the blocking/preemption time. I know that a StopWatch can be used to measure the total time for a task from start to finish, but this will also include the blocking time. Is there a way to exclude the blocking time?

Answer (score 4):

[System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread.TotalProcessorTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.totalprocessortime.aspx) will give you the amount of CPU time that a given thread has consumed.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but it seems that the values are updated every 15 milliseconds. Is there anyway to increase the precision of the execution times obtained from this property?

Comment: You need updates more that 66 times per second?  It returns a TimeSpan; the execution times themselves should be accurate to the tick level (100 nanosecond increments).

Comment: The way I currently measure each thread's execution time is by capturing the TotalProcessorTime at the beginning of the thread and then by another call to TotalProcessorTime at the end. Then I find the difference between the two values (note that a thread may be executed again, so this will find the time for a single execution). The problem is that for most threads (except the large ones), I get 0 as the difference. This is based on the ticks property of the timespans.